# Conky Widgets are Opening in their Own Windows

Tags: unity, 16.04, themes, customization, conky

I just upgraded to 16.04 and I'm getting all my customization set up again, but it seems that most Conky widgets are opening in their own window, instead of just appearing on the Desktop; although some are working correctly.

For example:

LSD (working properly):

[image]

Seamod (not working, opening in own window):

[image]

Since it's not affecting every single widget, I assume it could be an issue with the conkyrc with the widgets that aren't working, but this also never happened in 14.04 so I wasn't sure if maybe there was some compatibility issue in 16.04. My Google-fu has failed me in finding a solution.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 6):

Nevermind, figured it out. The following lines need to be present in the conkyrc file for the particular theme/widget/skin:

```
own_window_class conky
own_window yes
own_window_type desktop
```

EDIT:

Actually this only works for some skins. For Seamod, for example, I can only get it to appear in a second window or if it appears on the desktop, it disappears if I click on the desktop

EDIT2:

I think I figured out, there was a typo in the conkyrc.

```
own_window_hints undecorated,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
```

It said "undecorate" instead of "undecorated"