# Conky seamod GUI writing over iteself

Tags: conky

[image]

The picture explains it better than I can. I have edited the config to make window_type override instead of the default as I wanted it on the desktop not as a window, but window_type desktop was disappearing whenever I clicked on the desktop. Is there any way to fix this without reverting the previous problems?

- I have used the default seamod that comes with conky
- I have used conky-manager

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason is you need to change:

```
own_window_type override
```

to:

```
own_window_type normal
```

If this doesn't fix it, we'll need to see your whole Conky resource file (`~/.conkyrc`) posted into your question.

Comment: I've tried this and it makes it appear as a window (with title bar) rather than on the desktop. More detail in this, newer, question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/907647/conky-either-has-title-bar-dissapears-or-over-writes-itself

Comment: @J.Smith try: `double_buffer yes`.

Comment: It's already set to yes. I have tried changing it to no, as of yet it appears to be working but for a black background.

Comment: OK, when I make it transparent again (only pseudo-transparent works) it has the same problem again.

Comment: I use three lines for that:
1) `own_window_transparent no`
2) `own_window_argb_visual yes`
and 3) `own_window_argb_value 145  # semi-transparent`
Which has always worked for me and never really had it any other way.

Comment: That has a black background.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by switching to window_type normal and following instructions here:

[Conky Widgets are Opening in their Own Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812151/conky-widgets-are-opening-in-their-own-windows?rq=1)

```
own_window_class conky
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
```

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you [earned 15 reputation](/help/whats-reputation). Don't forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!