# Conky either has title bar, dissapears or over writes itself

Tags: unity, conky

I have been trying to set up Conky. Gothic works fine, but seamod has been giving me problems. I have tried setting the window_type as recommended elsewhere, but:

- normal has a title bar and appears in the side panel like a normal
  window. The suggested solution to this is to set the window_type to
  desktop
- Desktop disappears when I click on the desktop (left or right). The suggested solution to this is to set the window_type to normal  +
- Override has the problem depicted here:
  [Conky seamod GUI writing over iteself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907508/conky-seamod-gui-writing-over-iteself). Still not sure what triggers it, but I think it may be having two windows side-by-side (by dragging into the corner) or using the terminal
- Panel and dock appear to work as the should, but I do not want a
  panel or dock.

How do I display it on the desktop without it disappearing or having a title bar or writing over itself?

Conky seamod config file:

```
background yes
update_interval 1

cpu_avg_samples 1
net_avg_samples 2
temperature_unit celsius

double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes
text_buffer_size 2048

gap_x 0
gap_y 0
minimum_size 300 900
maximum_width 350

own_window yes
own_window_type desktop
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_colour 000000
own_window_argb_value 0
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below

border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0
alignment top_right


draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no

override_utf8_locale yes
use_xft yes
xftfont caviar dreams:size=10
xftalpha 0.5
uppercase no
```

Notes: I'm using unity and running from a persistent live USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by setting window_type to normal and following instructions here:
[Conky Widgets are Opening in their Own Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812151/conky-widgets-are-opening-in-their-own-windows?rq=1)